# Debian restarts itself after booting with a "not responding" error

Tags: debian, boot, grub

I had a stable Debian 6 install until earlier today, when some keys on my USB keyboard stopped working and my USB mouse buttons started to behave strangely. I did not installed anything new since the last time I shutdown my computer.

I ran `sudo reboot`, left to check on something else, then came back to see a screen like the following:

```
[nnnn.nn] not responding
[nnnn.nn] not responding
```

... where the `n`s were numbers (I don't know if the decimal point was always placed at the same spot). After a few seconds, my computer restarted.

This would happen every time after I got to the GRUB screen and selected Debian.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you get the same errors with the fallback image? Can you boot from another medium and check your logs?

Comment: nnnn.nn is the time since boot. What would be useful is the messages before “not responding” starts beind spammed. Press `Ctrl+S` to pause the display, `Ctrl+Q` to resume. Also run a memory test, strange symptoms like this are sometimes the cause of RAM going bad.

Comment: Hm, today the computer started working perfectly fine again. @Gilles, would this mean the RAM is going bad, and if so, even though the computer works fine, should I replace my RAM?

Comment: @JonathanChan With the symptoms you've seen so far, it could be just about any piece of hardware that's failing (including a loose wire somewhere). There are sure signs of RAM failure, but they involve data corruption, so it's better not to get them. I recommend running a memory test overnight anyway.